# 12.04 Dual Boot with Desktop and Server - what order to insall?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, server, system-installation, .desktop

In a couple of weeks I will have a new computer with no OS installed.  I want to set it up as a dual boot with Server as the default and Desktop as an option at boot time.  I want to make the installation of the two OSs as simple as possible.

*Which do I install first, Server or Desktop?*

I need a dual boot as I need to do application development on this machine that has all the hardware that I need  but need to do testing for deployment in a headless environment.

I'm planning to use 12.04 LTS since I have a vendor driver that has not been tested on later versions of the kernel.

I'm fairly new at LINUX

Comment: I would just install the desktop and do your development in KVM or VBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really doesn't matter, just install server then desktop if you want an arbitrary recommendation, it makes no difference other than the fact that the last installed one will be the default boot option in grub

Comment: if this answered your problem please mark it as solved by clicking the checkmark next to the answer